# Q-Learning values get too high

Tags: go, floating-point, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I've recently made an attempt to implement a basic Q-Learning algorithm in Golang. Note that I'm new to Reinforcement Learning and AI in general, so the error may very well be mine.

Here's how I implemented the solution to an m,n,k-game environment:
At each given time `t`, the agent holds the last state-action `(s, a)` and the acquired reward for it; the agent selects a move `a'` based on an Epsilon-greedy policy and calculates the reward `r`, then proceeds to update the value of `Q(s, a)` for time `t-1`

```
func (agent *RLAgent) learn(reward float64) {
    var mState = marshallState(agent.prevState, agent.id)
    var oldVal = agent.values[mState]

    agent.values[mState] = oldVal + (agent.LearningRate *
        (agent.prevScore + (agent.DiscountFactor * reward) - oldVal))
}
```

Note:

- `agent.prevState` holds previous state right after taking the action and before the environment responds (i.e. after the agent makes it's move and before the other player makes a move) I use that in place of the state-action tuple, but I'm not quite sure if that's the right approach
- `agent.prevScore` holds the reward to previous state-action
- The `reward` argument represents the reward for current step's state-action (`Qmax`)

With `agent.LearningRate = 0.2` and `agent.DiscountFactor = 0.8` the agent fails to reach 100K episodes because of state-action value overflow.
I'm using golang's `float64` (Standard IEEE 754-1985 double precision floating point variable) which overflows at around `±1.80×10^308` and yields `±Infiniti`. That's too big a value I'd say!

Here's the state of a model trained with a learning rate of `0.02` and a discount factor of `0.08` which got through 2M episodes (1M games with itself):

```
Reinforcement learning model report
Iterations: 2000000
Learned states: 4973
Maximum value: 88781786878142287058992045692178302709335321375413536179603017129368394119653322992958428880260210391115335655910912645569618040471973513955473468092393367618971462560382976.000000
Minimum value: 0.000000
```

The reward function returns:

- Agent won: 1
- Agent lost: -1
- Draw: 0
- Game continues: 0.5

But you can see that the minimum value is zero, and the maximum value is too high.

It may be worth mentioning that with a simpler learning method I found in a python script works perfectly fine and feels actually more intelligent! When I play with it, most of the time the result is a draw (it even wins if I play carelessly), whereas with the standard Q-Learning method, I can't even let it win!

```
agent.values[mState] = oldVal + (agent.LearningRate * (reward - agent.prevScore))
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?
Is that kind of state-action value normal in Q-Learning?!

---

**Update:**
After reading Pablo's answer and the slight but important edit that Nick provided to this question, I realized the problem was `prevScore` containing the Q-value of previous step (equal to `oldVal`) instead of the reward of the previous step (in this example, -1, 0, 0.5 or 1).

After that change, the agent now behaves normally and after 2M episodes, the state of the model is as follows:

```
Reinforcement learning model report
Iterations: 2000000
Learned states: 5477
Maximum value: 1.090465
Minimum value: -0.554718
```

and out of 5 games with the agent, there were 2 wins for me (the agent did not recognize that I had two stones in a row) and 3 draws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood well, in your Q-learning update rule, you are using the current reward and the previous reward. However, the Q-learning rule only uses one reward (`x` are states and `u` are actions):
[image]

On the other hand, you are assuming that the current reward is the same that `Qmax` value, which is not true. So probably you are misunderstanding the Q-learning algorithm.

Comment: It may very well be that I chose the wrong source to learn from. In the current system `prevScore = value of (s, a)`, `reward = value of (s', a')`

Comment: and `reward` is often a big number (value), not `{-1, 0, 1}`. I think I see the problem now!

Comment: ye chand sal dir soaleta didam.

Comment: @EhsanJeihani It had me for a couple of days! Really fun when I got it to work though

Answer (score 3):

The reward function is likely the problem. Reinforcement learning methods try to maximize the **expected total reward**; it gets a positive reward for every time step in the game, so the optimal policy is to play as long as possible! The q-values, which define the *value function* (expected total reward of taking an action in a state then behaving optimally) are growing because the correct expectation is unbounded. To incentivize winning, you should have a negative reward every time step (kind of like telling the agent to hurry up and win).

See 3.2 Goals and Rewards in *Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction* for more insight into the purpose and definition of reward signals. The problem you are facing is actually exercise 3.5 in the book.

Comment: That was an interesting point which I totally missed. I did try using different values when the game continues: Anything higher than `-0.45` results to the same problem, and lower values produce negative rewards for all state-actions (maximum value = 0) and the agent still fails to win. Any thoughts?

Comment: This issue can be related with an undesired optimal policy or behaviour, but not justifies the divergence of the Q-values...

Comment: Thanks Nick, that edit really helped me see what Pablo was trying to say! I used a python implementation from github as a source to be able to make sense of this, but apparently I chose the wrong one and took too much of it!